# Oracle Roles and privileges hierarchy

Tags: oracle, roles, privileges

Good morning,

I'm trying to understand one thing in Oracle database Roles and privileges:

So, i am trying to create two Roles: Programmer and Manager.

The idea for Programmer role users, is to create and insert into tables.
The idea for Manager role users, is to have acess to Programmer role privileges, PLUS update records.

And i thought that if i granted the Programmer role to Manager role, this last one could:

1. Create a table (from programmer role);
2. Insert into a table (from programmer role);
3. Update a record in the table (privilege set to the Manager role);

But through SQL developer, i grant Programmer role to Manager role, and when i connect to the database using a Manager User, i can't find tables created on SYSTEM.A (for example).

Do i need to grant explicity on Manager role also can create and insert? If so, what's the point of the inheritance?

---

**SOLUTION**

Programmer role: Insert && create table privileges;
Manager role: Update && Select any table privileges;

Since my goal was to put Manager users inherit Programmer role privileges, this can be achieved like this:

(After setting the roles and privileges):

- DBA > ROLES > EDIT MANAGER ROLE > GRANTED ROLES > SELECT PROGRAMMER ROLE.
- Disconnect any manager session, and re-connect.

Open a Manager SQL sheet and try to create a table and select, insert and update it. You'll see that Manager has adopter privileges from "programmer" role.

Comment: You understand correctly. Maybe show how you grant the permissions.

Comment: @Haki, thanks for your reply. Do you want me to show how do i set permissions? I do everything using SQL developer, but i can do it using SQL. I know that i set the roles and permissions correctly, because i'm testing everytime. However, this concept of inheritance  that i thought it exists, left me kind of sad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is a non-procedural language.  Having that said,you don't need to think about inheritance here.  Instead, Grant create,insert and update privileges on manager role explicitly.

Here's what you can do:

1- Create programmer and manager role:

SQL> CREATE ROLE role_name IDENTIFIED by pass_word;

2- Then GRANT  privileges (your requirement here) to each role:

SQL> GRANT privilege TO role_name;

3- Grant users(programmers & managers) privileges by granting each user(depends whether he is a manager or a programmer) to a particular role.

SQL> GRANT role_name TO  user_name;

You may find the following link useful for more details:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm#21065

Comment: thank you for your reply. The part of granting permissions to Users, i understand. What was bugging me off was the part that you can grant a role A to role B but all privileges that A has don't pass to B. This is kind of stupid in some way...But thank you for your reply!

Comment: @Sammy, You are welcome.  I see where the confusion part was in your question.  You thought about inheriting a feature/grant privilege from a role to another role, just like what the procedural languages such as C++,Java...etc do .   SQL is a non procedural language (That's what you haven't considered when thinking about it).

Comment: Ithappens that i just found the solution i wanted. By following the instructions i've wrote above, it is possible to inherit privileges from one role to anothe! :).

Kind regards